# Getting a blank layout (probably activity_main.xml) instead of requested layout (add_new_contact.xml)

Tags: android, android-layout

I get a blank layout instead of requested layout(add_new_contact)
1.MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.addressbookapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // The Intent is used to perform an operation
    Intent      intent;
    TextView    contactId;

    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

    // Method invoked first, when the Activity is first called
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Get saved data, if any 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set the main view
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        //Get all data from database and store it in an array
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = dbTools.getAllContacts();

        if (contactList.size() != 0) {
            ListView listView = getListView();

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    contactId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactId);
                    String contactIdValue = contactId.getText().toString();

                    // Intent to get application that owns this Activity
                    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), edit_contact.class);
                    // Put additional key value pair to use in Edit Contact
                    theIntent.putExtra("contactId", contactIdValue);
                    startActivity(theIntent);

                }

            });


            // List Adapter is a bridge between ListView and ListView data
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList, R.layout.contact_entry, 
                    new String[] {"contactId", "lastName", "firstName"},
                    new int[] {R.id.contactId, R.id.lastName, R.id.firstName});

            // setListAdapter provides cursor for the list view
            // The cursor provides access to the  data
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    // Call the below function showAddContact when New Contact is called
    //           showAddContact
    public void showAddContact(View view) {
        Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), NewContact.class);
        startActivity(theIntent);
    }
}
```

2.NewContact.java

```
package com.example.addressbookapp;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewContact extends Activity {

    EditText firstName;
    EditText lastName;
    EditText phoneNumber;
    EditText emailAddress;
    EditText homeAddress;

    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

    public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_contact);

        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        homeAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeAddress);

    }

    public void addNewContact(View view){
        HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        queryValuesMap.put("firstName", firstName.getText().toString());
        queryValuesMap.put("lastName", lastName.getText().toString());
        queryValuesMap.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber.getText().toString());
        queryValuesMap.put("emailAddress", emailAddress.getText().toString());
        queryValuesMap.put("homeAddress", homeAddress.getText().toString());

        dbTools.insertContact(queryValuesMap);
        this.callMainActivity(view);
    }

    public void callMainActivity(View view){
        Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(theIntent);
    }
}
```

3.add_new_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#000">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editContactTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/add_button" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fistNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/first_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/last_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp" >

        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/phone_number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp" >

        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/email_address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:text="@string/home_address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/homeAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_data" 
            android:onClick="addNewContact"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </TableRow>      
</TableLayout>
```

4. AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.addressbookapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.addressbookapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.addressbookapp.NewContact"
            android:label="" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.addressbookapp.edit_contact"
            android:label="" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not overriding `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, you're declaring a method `onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

```
/*
 * yours
 */
public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

/* 
 * should be
 */
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

Comment: When do you override and When do you not. There is no override for editcontact and is working

Comment: You don't necessarily _need_ the `@Override` annotation, but it will allow the compiler to warn you of these things. In your case, it would've said something like "Does not override a parent method".